# What if a mutex managed by a unique_lock is destroyed?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

```
void Fn() {
  std::mutex* mutex = new std::mutex;
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(*mutex);
  delete mutex;
}
```

Is there undefined behavior in the snippet above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in UB territory even before the lock's destructor runs. §30.4.1.2.1 [thread.mutex.class]/p5:

> The behavior of a program is undefined if it destroys a `mutex` object
>   owned by any thread or a thread terminates while owning a `mutex`
>   object.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course there's undefined behaviour. The lock's destructor will try to call `mutex->unlock()`, which will dereference an invalid pointer.